# Kerberos for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kerberos

We are using the combination of hadoop and elasticsearch on production. We'd like to use Kerberos to centralise the authentication.

Does Elastic Search support Kerberos? Or is there a plugin around for this?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout Search Guard 2 plugin: https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard

```
 Advanced functionalities like LDAP and **Kerberos** authentication/authorization as well as DLS/FLS will be available soon as separate and commercial licensed add-ons (but still Open Source).
```

Answer (score 0):

[Elasticsearch 6.4+ supports Kerberos](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-secure-your-elasticsearch-clusters-using-kerberos) as part of the Elastic stack security features.

Currently, [the Kerberos realm](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/configuring-kerberos-realm.html) [requires a platinum license](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) to use.